# Error receiving broadcast Intent { act=android.net.wifi.SCAN_RESULTS }

Tags: java, android, android-intent, broadcastreceiver

okay, the full error is

```
06-19 01:07:57.421: E/AndroidRuntime(4478): java.lang.RuntimeException: Error 
receiving broadcast Intent { act=android.net.wifi.SCAN_RESULTS } in 
com.blucalc.netfind.WiFiScanReceiver@40521ba0
```

com.blucalc.netfind is my package
WiFiScanReceiver is the class its crashing in.

the class is here:

```
package com.blucalc.netfind;

import java.util.List;

import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.wifi.ScanResult;

public class WiFiScanReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    NetworkfinderActivity netfinder;

    public WiFiScanReceiver(NetworkfinderActivity netfinder) {
        super();
        this.netfinder = netfinder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context c, Intent intent) {
        System.out.println("onReceive(Context=" + c.toString() + "Intent="
                + intent.toString());
        List<ScanResult> results = netfinder.wifi.getScanResults();
        netfinder.processResults(results);
    }

}
```

NetworkfinderActivity is the main class thing.

the really strange thing about the error is, it only happens on the second time this function is called. whether thats because of the different data i dont know, i can't test.

can someone please help me?

edit1:
as requested, androidmanifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.blucalc.netfind"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="7" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE" />
    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <activity
            android:name=".NetworkfinderActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

here's the main class. where all the fun happens.

```
//some code borrowed from http://marakana.com/forums/android/examples/40.html
package com.blucalc.netfind;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.IntentFilter;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.net.wifi.*;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.*;


public class NetworkfinderActivity extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    WifiManager wifi;
    BroadcastReceiver receiver;
    List<FrameLayout> netlist;
    LinearLayout ll;
    Button b;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        System.out.println("start of main constructor");
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        //a couple interface elements I want to access
        ll = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.networkList);
        b = (Button)findViewById(R.id.refreshButton);
        //initialisation of some memory
        netlist=new ArrayList<FrameLayout>();
        //where all network info comes from
        wifi=(WifiManager)getSystemService(WIFI_SERVICE);
        // Register Broadcast Receiver
        receiver = new WiFiScanReceiver(this);
        registerReceiver(receiver, new IntentFilter(
                WifiManager.SCAN_RESULTS_AVAILABLE_ACTION));

        b.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {;
            System.out.println("clicked");
                ll.removeAllViews();
                netlist.clear();

                wifi.startScan();
            }
        });
        System.out.println("end of main constructor");
    }

    @Override
    public void onStop() {
        unregisterReceiver(receiver);
    }
    public void processResults(List<ScanResult> results)
    {
        System.out.println("processResults(results "+results.toString());
        ll.removeAllViews();
        netlist.clear();
        for (ScanResult result:results)
        {
            readResult(result);
        }
        System.out.println("end of processResults");

    }
    public void readResult(ScanResult result)
    {
        System.out.println("readResult(result "+result.toString());
        FrameLayout frame=new FrameLayout(this);
        TextView ssid=new TextView(this);
        TextView strength=new TextView(this);
        System.out.println("1");
        int level=result.level;
        System.out.println("level="+level);
        int signal=WifiManager.calculateSignalLevel(level, 100)+1;
        //signal will be strength of the signal as a percent (from 1 to 100)
        System.out.println("signal="+signal);

        strength.setText(new Integer(signal).toString());
        ssid.setText(result.SSID);
        TextView cheat=new TextView(this);
        cheat.setText(result.toString());

//      frame.addView(ssid);
//      frame.addView(strength);
        frame.addView(cheat);

        netlist.add(frame);
        ll.addView(netlist.get(netlist.size()-1));
        System.out.println("end of readResults");
    }

}
```

and last but not least, here's the entire output, plus all error messages.

```
06-20 20:40:06.835: I/ApplicationPackageManager(2399): cscCountry is not German : XSA
06-20 20:40:06.835: I/System.out(2399): start of main constructor
06-20 20:40:06.867: V/WifiProgressStore(2399): WifiProgressStore Created
06-20 20:40:06.867: I/System.out(2399): end of main constructor
06-20 20:40:16.765: I/System.out(2399): clicked
06-20 20:40:17.351: I/System.out(2399): onReceive(Context=com.blucalc.netfind.NetworkfinderActivity@40518050Intent=Intent { act=android.net.wifi.SCAN_RESULTS }
06-20 20:40:17.363: I/System.out(2399): processResults(results [SSID: BluCalculator, BSSID: f4:ec:38:a9:1d:56, capabilities: [WPA-PSK-TKIP+CCMP][WPA2-PSK-TKIP+CCMP][WPS], level: -51, frequency: 2412, SSID: BigAir, BSSID: 06:27:22:b3:41:7e, capabilities: , level: -72, frequency: 2437, SSID: BigAir, BSSID: 06:27:22:5f:56:d8, capabilities: , level: -87, frequency: 2437]
06-20 20:40:17.367: I/System.out(2399): readResult(result SSID: BluCalculator, BSSID: f4:ec:38:a9:1d:56, capabilities: [WPA-PSK-TKIP+CCMP][WPA2-PSK-TKIP+CCMP][WPS], level: -51, frequency: 2412
06-20 20:40:17.375: I/System.out(2399): 1
06-20 20:40:17.375: I/System.out(2399): level=-51
06-20 20:40:17.375: I/System.out(2399): signal=100
06-20 20:40:17.378: I/System.out(2399): end of readResults
06-20 20:40:17.382: I/System.out(2399): readResult(result SSID: BigAir, BSSID: 06:27:22:b3:41:7e, capabilities: , level: -72, frequency: 2437
06-20 20:40:17.390: I/System.out(2399): 1
06-20 20:40:17.390: I/System.out(2399): level=-72
06-20 20:40:17.394: D/AndroidRuntime(2399): Shutting down VM
06-20 20:40:17.394: W/dalvikvm(2399): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40015578)
06-20 20:40:17.402: E/AndroidRuntime(2399): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-20 20:40:17.402: E/AndroidRuntime(2399): java.lang.RuntimeException: Error receiving broadcast Intent { act=android.net.wifi.SCAN_RESULTS } in com.blucalc.netfind.WiFiScanReceiver@40520ec0
06-20 20:40:17.402: E/AndroidRuntime(2399):     at android.app.LoadedApk$ReceiverDispatcher$Args.run(LoadedApk.java:722)
06-20 20:40:17.402: E/AndroidRuntime(2399):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
06-20 20:40:17.402: E/AndroidRuntime(2399):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
06-20 20:40:17.402: E/AndroidRuntime(2399):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
06-20 20:40:17.402: E/AndroidRuntime(2399):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3687)
06-20 20:40:17.402: E/AndroidRuntime(2399):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-20 20:40:17.402: E/AndroidRuntime(2399):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
06-20 20:40:17.402: E/AndroidRuntime(2399):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:842)
06-20 20:40:17.402: E/AndroidRuntime(2399):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:600)
06-20 20:40:17.402: E/AndroidRuntime(2399):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
06-20 20:40:17.402: E/AndroidRuntime(2399): Caused by: java.lang.ArithmeticException: divide by zero
06-20 20:40:17.402: E/AndroidRuntime(2399):     at android.net.wifi.WifiManager.calculateSignalLevel(WifiManager.java:957)
06-20 20:40:17.402: E/AndroidRuntime(2399):     at com.blucalc.netfind.NetworkfinderActivity.readResult(NetworkfinderActivity.java:79)
06-20 20:40:17.402: E/AndroidRuntime(2399):     at com.blucalc.netfind.NetworkfinderActivity.processResults(NetworkfinderActivity.java:65)
06-20 20:40:17.402: E/AndroidRuntime(2399):     at com.blucalc.netfind.WiFiScanReceiver.onReceive(WiFiScanReceiver.java:23)
06-20 20:40:17.402: E/AndroidRuntime(2399):     at android.app.LoadedApk$ReceiverDispatcher$Args.run(LoadedApk.java:709)
06-20 20:40:17.402: E/AndroidRuntime(2399):     ... 9 more
```

Comment: Can you also provide your AndroidManifest.xml? Also, what line is the crash on? It would be helpful if you could provide the entire stack trace.

Comment: @cklab will provide manifest in a moment.

and i dont think it gives me the line it crashes

and what does "the entire stack trace" mean?

Comment: By the entire stack trace I mean the output that gave you the error above. It would include the file names, line numbers, and function calls that lead to the exception.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**ANSWER UPDATED**

If you look into your stack trace, you will find another exception that points out the real problem:

```
06-20 20:40:17.402: E/AndroidRuntime(2399): Caused by: java.lang.ArithmeticException: divide by zero
06-20 20:40:17.402: E/AndroidRuntime(2399):     at android.net.wifi.WifiManager.calculateSignalLevel(WifiManager.java:957)
06-20 20:40:17.402: E/AndroidRuntime(2399):     at com.blucalc.netfind.NetworkfinderActivity.readResult(NetworkfinderActivity.java:79)
06-20 20:40:17.402: E/AndroidRuntime(2399):     at com.blucalc.netfind.NetworkfinderActivity.processResults(NetworkfinderActivity.java:65)
06-20 20:40:17.402: E/AndroidRuntime(2399):     at com.blucalc.netfind.WiFiScanReceiver.onReceive(WiFiScanReceiver.java:23)
06-20 20:40:17.402: E/AndroidRuntime(2399):     at android.app.LoadedApk$ReceiverDispatcher$Args.run(LoadedApk.java:709)
06-20 20:40:17.402: E/AndroidRuntime(2399):     ... 9 more
```

Note the part that says

```
    6-20 20:40:17.402: E/AndroidRuntime(2399): Caused by: java.lang.ArithmeticException: divide by zero
```

The method you are attempting to access (`calculateSignalLevel`) has a known [bug](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=2555) in it. You can find a post relating to the use `calculateSignalLevel` (that includes the code implementation of `calculateSignalLevel`) at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2873469/issue-with-wifimanager-calculatesignallevelrssi-5) question (also note Ridcully's comment on Lars' answer).

The problem is most likely your use of `100` here:

```
WifiManager.calculateSignalLevel(level, 100);
```

When this number is greater than 45, you will get a divide by zero exception. Try stepping through the method with a value of 100 for `partitionLevel` and observe the outcome.

Comment: where abouts do i put that in the manifest?

edit: also, i've already defined it as a reciever in the activity class. im gonna go ahead and put that class in as well.

Comment: @blucalculatr answer updated to reflect the new information you provided :)

Comment: sweet! setting it to something lower than 45 fixed it. thankyou so much. now i can get back to ordinary errors.

Comment: @blucalculatr `To mark an answer as accepted, click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from hollow to green`. See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work.

Comment: The easy solution is simply use a value less than 45.